# why do i have this PHP version "7.2.30" as the current PHP vesion?

Tags: symfony, vagrant, homestead

When i run the domain i configured in "laravel/Homestead" which is "symfony-01.local"
i get this error

> Fatal Error: composer.lock was created for PHP version 7.4 or higher but the current PHP version is 
>   7.2.30.

My homestead PHP version is:[version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6Zj4.png)

My Current PHP version is :[version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11aUR.png)

My Homestead composer.lock : [composer.lock](https://filebin.net/83d8o4any6y1b3sk/composer.lock?t=x6ntenuk)

My symfony project composer.lock in vagrant:[composer.lock](https://filebin.net/t0t5qln9xzljgvxq/composer.lock?t=fbdvmo90)

Comment: 7.3.19 is still a lower version than 7.4. Maybe simply the error message is wrong

Comment: Maybe. But if it wasn't wrong then where this error came from.

Comment: You probably have 7.2.3 installed and composer is using that incorrectly

Comment: Its for sure a problem with the PATH that you're using or that it is using.  Whatever, the version you're using is wrong.  Also, don't link to images to show the versions, just typing them will be sufficient.

Comment: do you *want* the php version 7.2.30 to be set? (reason might be that the target system has this version and won't upgrade). if not, you can just *remove* the setting from your composer.json and run composer update without any parameters. the setting in composer.json is for forcing composer to *assume* the set php version. it's usually not a requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found a solution
i had to enforce php version for installed composer packages

The solution is to go to the homestead folder and run these commands:

> composer config platform.php 7.2.30

This will set the platform option automatically (*Note : you can edit it manually in composer.json*) and it will be used to download and update composers based on the platform requirement but what i really needed is to ignore it, to do that i used this:

> composer update phpunit/phpunit --ignore-platform-reqs